# JCL equivalent of CEMT NEWCOPY

Tags: mainframe, cics

I am looking for the JCL equivalent of NEWCOPY method in CEMT/CICS:

```
CEMT SET PROG(xxxx) NEWCOPY
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I don't understand your question. Are you trying to write a JCL procedure that will perform a CICS NEWCOPY?

Comment: JCL does not have a direct way to issue a NEWCOPY command. There are two ways outside of CICS to issue a CEMT NEWCOPY, which are the MODIFY console command and the EXCI interface. Now, as stated below, JCL can issue an operator command

Answer (score 4):

If your answer to NealB's question is "Yes," then here are some options.

1. Invoke CEMT via an operator command.  One way to do this is to run
   [SDSF in batch](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/zos/2.4.0?topic=guide-using-sdsf-in-batch), another is to use the [TSO CONSOLE](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/zos/2.4.0?topic=syntax-console-command) command.  Be
   advised that this requires authorization.
2. Write a program in your preferred programming language and invoke the
   CICS System Programming API [SET PROGRAM](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/cics-ts/5.6?topic=sc-set-program).  Then write another
   program, to be executed in batch, that uses the External CICS
   Interface (EXCI) to invoke your CICS program that does the SET
   PROGRAM.
3. There exist third-party tools that do what you want, DADS
   PLUS is one.  We use a facility built into our change management
   system, Change Man from Serena.  There are likely others.

Comment: Could also look into [CICS Batch Interface](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/cicsts/v4r2/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.cics.cm.doc%2Fccv-batch.htm)

Answer (score 0):

You can just use the JCL `COMMAND` to embed the COMMAND in your job stream:

```
//CMD1 COMMAND 'F CICSRGN1, CEMT SET PROG(xxx) NEWCOPY'
```

I'm not sure of the syntax, but it is exactly what you would use from an opperator terminal.